# android multiscreen issue between screens

Tags: android, multiscreen

I have a multi screen app that only the first button works. alll of the other buttons crash when they go to the next java file. In the manifest I have all of them listed but I have no idea why its crashing. any ideas? 
    package com.mike.BrowserScreen;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.view.*; 
    import android.content.Intent;

```
 public class BrowserScreenActivity extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button flea=null; 
Button bu1=null;
Button bu2=null;
Button bu3=null;
TextView tv1=null; 
TextView tv2=null;
TextView tv3=null; 
TextView tv4=null; 
TextView tv5=null;
TextView tv6=null; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    flea=(Button)findViewById(R.id.flea);
    bu1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bu1);
    bu2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bu2);
    bu3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bu3);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
    tv5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv5);
    tv6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv6);
    flea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
    public void onClick(View v){ 
     Intent myIntent=new Intent(v.getContext(),SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent); 
                }
          });

        bu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
      public void onClick(View v){ 
       Intent myIntent1=new Intent(v.getContext(),ThirdActivity.class);
     startActivity(myIntent1); 
           }
         }); 
      bu2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
      public void onClick(View v){ 
      Intent myIntent2=new Intent(v.getContext(),FourthActivity.class);
      startActivity(myIntent2); 
          }
     });
     bu3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
      public void onClick(View v){ 
      Intent myIntent3=new Intent(v.getContext(),FifthActivity.class);
      startActivity(myIntent3); 
        }
         }); 
      } 
    }
```

Heres the manifest

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".BrowserScreenActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ForthActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".FifthActivity"></activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

---

i figured it out in the other java files i forgot to change it to the right xml file.I will have another question on launching a website from a textview or button

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?
Your code seems to be fine

Comment: what's the error you are getting, is it a NullPointerException ??

Comment: The application crashes and says "The application browserscreen (process.com.mike.Browscreen) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while starting new Activity..

Instead of `v.getContext()` use `BrowserScreenActivity.this` or `getBaseContext()`

like this

```
 flea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
    public void onClick(View v){ 
     Intent myIntent=new Intent(BrowserScreenActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent); 
                }
          });
```

Comment: Still crashes when I tried that is there anything else I should upload liek the manifest file or the XML or the other classes?